# Android: APIs for live chat in android

Tags: android, livechat

can anyone please suggest some tutorials  or APIs for making live chat applications in android.
Thanks .....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on what kind of chat you  want. If it is one on one instant messaging you can look for java libraries that implement the XMPP protocol. If you want to do group chats you might want to checkout libraries that implement the IRC protocol.

**Smack** - java xmpp libary -  http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

**aSmack** - android fork of smack - http://code.google.com/p/asmack/

**ejabberd** - xmpp server - http://www.ejabberd.im/

**Martyer** - java irc library - http://martyr.sourceforge.net/

**Jerklib** - java irc library - http://jerklib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi, can u please suggest me some tutorials

Comment: There is a guy using the Smack library on Android here http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/