# IRC library for Android (From 2.3.3 to 4.0.3 )?

Tags: android, eclipse, irc, android-library

Is there **any android-compatible (from 2.3.3 to 4.0.3) IRC library for Android**?

As of yet I am unable to find one, and any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: r u looking for live chat here is the [link ..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703669/android-apis-for-live-chat-in-android) let me know is it helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try http://www.yaaic.org

They have the souce in GitHub
https://github.com/pocmo/Yaaic/

Comment: Who knew an. It's compatible with Android. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! I'm the author of Yaaic. Yaaic uses the PircBot library (with some patches for bouncers and using SSL) which is a Java-based IRC library that also works flawlessly with Android: http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php